# Swift- Detect several taps on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to detect when my users tap 4 times on a disabled UITableViewCell to re-enable it.

I am obviously not getting feedback from didSelectRowAt because the cell is not active. Is there any other way to get this information?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add a gesture recognizer to the table view and find the cell on where the tap occurred by getting the location of the tap and passing that to `tableView.index​Path​For​Row(at:​)`.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer and a counter

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I found an answer by using a tap gesture recognizer which seems to accept a variable for number of taps (I guess it defaults to 1).

The code works like this:

```
//Add gesture recognizer on Table View Cell
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cellTapped(tap:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 4
        tableview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

I then work with the location to enable my cell:

```
func tableTapped(tap: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let tapLoc = tap.location(in: self.view)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLoc)

        gifs[indexPath!.row].sent = false

    }
```